# Hazelcastrepository is connecting with Database and not with Hazelcast server

Tags: spring, hazelcast

I am integrating Hazelcast in existing spring project(Not spring boot) and app is not connecting with Hazlecast server to get the data instead it is fetching from Database .

Hazelcast client is sucesfully making the connection with server which can be seen from the startup logs.

Repository class:

```
 public interface CustomerKVEntity extends HazelcastRepository<Customer, Long> {

        List<Customer> findByPostalCode(String postalCode);
}
```

CustomerKVEntity class (Field names omitted since irrelevant)

```
    @KeySpace
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "customer")
    public class Customer implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "customerSeq", sequenceName = "SEQ_CUSTOMER", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "customerSeq")
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Long id;

....
}
```

Datasource added is using BoneCP connection pooling as shown below and annotated with @Bean. NOt sure if this is a problem.

```
 BoneCPDataSource ds = new BoneCPDataSource();
 ds.setJdbcUrl(url);
```

When i call findByPostalCode in repository data is fetching from the database and not from the Hazelcast server. What could be the reason , please help !

**EDIT:**

Hazelcast COnfiguration (hazelcast-client.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast-client
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
        http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-3.11.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- Look for some of the cluster -->
    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>127.0.0.1:5701</address>
            <address>127.0.0.1:5702</address>
        </cluster-members>
    </network>

</hazelcast-client>
```

In my COnfigruation annotated class added this bean:

```
@Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() throws Exception {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new XmlClientConfigBuilder("hazelcast-client.xml").build();
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }
```

Comment: According to your mention about Hazelcast server connection; What did you try to connect Hazelcast server via your Spring application? May you share those trials additionally?(Hazelcast configuration, any configuration bean etc...)

Comment: @İlkerKorkut thanks for the reponse . edited my question :)

Comment: @İlkerKorkut I was using this blog as referene. https://hazelcast.com/blog/step-away-database/ This is working fine even with my oracle DB. BUt when i integrate that client part to my existing project * which is not a spring boot project, ) its not fetching data from Hazelcast server but its fecthing from DB. Is that datasource bean matters?